# Meaning of underscore

Tags: r, shiny

What is the function of an underscore in R? For example, in the code below, the line: `input$tbl_rows_current`; determines that the current data being displayed is placed into the variable `filtered_data`; however, if I change it to `input$tbl_rows_all`, all the data filtered is placed into the variable `filtered data`.

I understand how it functions here, but what is its general use?

```
ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl'),
           plotOutput('plot1')
)

server = function(input, output) {   
 output$tbl = renderDataTable({
    datatable(KSI, filter="top",rownames=TRUE,options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
})
output$plot1 = renderPlot({  
   filtered_data <- as.numeric(*input$tbl_rows_current*)     
   print(filtered_data)   
 })
}  
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Please only use the `rstudio` tag if your question concerns the RStudio code editor. You wouldn't use a `pen-and-paper` tag when asking a question about grammar!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Underscores are not semantically meaningful, they're just part of the variable name. (In the prehistoric era, `_` was synonymous with the assignment operator `<-` and couldn't be used in variable names.) `tbl_rows_current` and `tbl_rows_all` are just two particular elements of the `input` list. Depending on the preferences of the author, they could equally well have been called

- `tblrowscurrent` and `tblrowsall`
- `TblRowsCurrent` and `TblRowsAll`
- `tbl.rows.current` and `tbl.rows.all`
- `oranges` and `jackhammers`

If you like this sort of thing, check out [Are there any official naming conventions for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013545/are-there-any-official-naming-conventions-for-r)

Note, however, that *you* can't change these names; only the original package author could have. These elements are defined not in your code, but on the shiny side -- it's part of the shiny API/interface that it's expecting to see these particular elements (i.e., elements with these particular names).

Comment: +1 but it’s worth pointing out that it’s not a *subjective* preference: I can’t fault option 2 (though I personally hate it) but all the other options are objectively inferior.

Comment: this is the stuff of flame wars.  I know an R Core member who prefers dot-separated `x.y` to snake case `x_y` because (1) it's traditional in old-fashioned R code and (2) he claims it's easier not to have to hit the shift key (!)

Comment: But it simply clashes with S3 dispatch, there’s an objective argument for why this convention is bad.

Comment: I happen to agree with you.  I'm just saying it gets contentious.

Comment: There are many different opinions out there. Here's Google's "style guide" for R, advocating dot-separated identifiers and discouraging the use of the snake case: https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for the response. The penny is on the ledge but it hasn't quite dropped. If I change the code to `input$tblrowsall`; I get no output. At what point have I defined these elements in my input list? This is interesting as going from `all` to `current` changes nothing in my output. I thought this may have been a dev tools upgrade problem but perhaps I've misunderstood something more fundemental?

Comment: these elements are defined not in your code, but on the shiny side -- it's part of the shiny API/interface that it's expecting to see these particular elements (i.e., elements with these particular names)