# In R where does a variable named starting with a dot stores?

Tags: r, global-variables

I am curious about variables named starting with a dot. 
e.g.

```
.var <- 100
```

It does not belong to the Global environment. What environment does this variable belong to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
> ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv)
[1] ".Random.seed" ".var"         "a"
```

Look at the man page for `ls()` by typing `?"ls"` in the console

Below is the quote from the man page for `all.names` argument to be passed into `ls()`. The environment to look for can be controlled by the `envir` argument of `ls` command.

By default, `ls(all.names = TRUE)` will search for objects in the global environment.

> **all.names:** a logical value. If TRUE, all object names are returned. If FALSE, names which begin with a . are omitted.

Also by passing the environment value to `name` argument, one can list all visible and hidden objects of that environment.

```
search()
ls(name = .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE)
ls(name = "package:base", all.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining your answer -- code-only answers can be hard interpret for less experienced users ...