# How can I get a listing of al the unqualified names that can be found in the current scope?

Tags: r, scope

How can I get a listing of ***all*** the unqualified names that can be found in the current scope?

---

If your answer is `ls`, please specify exactly what arguments/options I must pass to `ls`.  Ditto for `objects`.

For example, after running `library(splines)`, what arguments I must pass to `ls` so that the results will include `"backSpline"` (along with `"library"`, and `"c"`, and `"matrix"`, and all the other identifiers that are in scope by default).

---

Here's a clarification for the person who voted to close this question for lack of clarity.

Please follow these steps.

```
## 1. Start an `R` session like this (or the equivalent for your system):

% R_PROFILE_USER= /usr/bin/R --quiet
>

## 2. Evaluate the following expression, and note that there's no error;
##    (BTW, `c` is an example of an unqualified name)

> class(c)
[1] "function"

## 3. Evaluate the following expression, and note the "not found" in the error
##    message; (`backSpline` is also an unqualified name)

> class(backSpline)
Error: object 'backSpline' not found

## 4. Evaluate the following expression, and note that this time there is no
##    error; (`splines::backSpline` is an example of a qualified name)

> class(splines::backSpline)
[1] "function"

## 5. Evaluate the following expression

> library(splines)

## 6. Now, once again, evaluate the expression from (4) above, and note that
##    there's no error

> class(backSpline)
[1] "function"

## 7. (Optional) Confirm that evaluating the expression from (2) still produces
##    no error

> class(c)
[1] "function"
```

At the end of the steps described above, the name `backSpline` is "found" in the current scope (whereas it wasn't at the beginning, according to the error message in (3)).  In contrast, at all times, `c` was found in the current scope.

I am looking for an expression that will evaluate to a listing (or, to more precise, a vector of strings) containing all the names that are "found" in the current scope.  If this expression is evaluated at a point before (5) above, the resulting listing should include the string `"c"`, and should *not* include the string `"backSpline"`; and if it is evaluated immediately after (5) above, it should contain both strings `"c"` and `"backSpline"`.

If the above is still not clear enough, please be kind enough to spell out what is it that you still don't understand.

Comment: That's a whole lot of functions, if I understand you correctly. You can try this: `f <- c(); for (s in search() ) { f <- append(f, ls(s))}` Does this do what you want?

Comment: Maybe `apropos(".")`? Maybe with `where = TRUE`? Not sure quite what you mean by "unqualified" names.

Comment: Check if this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448219/1691723.

Comment: @Gregor: `apropos(".")` is to be the best solution I've found so far.  Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Chrisss: if you replace `ls(s)` with `ls(s, all.names = TRUE)` the result is the same as what Gregor's `apropos(".")` produces.

Comment: @kjo Quite right. In fact, the internals of `apropos` does exactly that: Loops over the packages identified by `search()` and applies `ls(..., all.names = TRUE)` to each one with some optional regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `apropos`. You need to specify a search string, but `""` or `"."` should match everything.

As pointed out in comments, this is essentially a wrapper for `unlist(sapply(search(), ls, all.names = T))`. This is useful to understand because it can help if you only want to search, say, a specific attached namespace.